# Align right single for select no option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I change style (For example: adding: `text-algin` or `dir` single for option) one of the elements `select` or `option`, so that does not change style both and only change style one of them.

I tried to do the `align right` single for `select` and, `option` In the previous case remain(Means: `align left`). But don't work. What do i do?

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DEwvw/)**

```
select {
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: right;
    width: 300px;
}​

<select>
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="" value="" style="display: none;">Select</option>
    <option>option 1</option>
    <option>option 2</option>
    <option>option 3</option>
</select>​
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you reword it a bit?

Comment: I want put `direction: rtl;` for select and `direction: ltr;` for option, I hope that is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Aligning a single option is not supported by all browsers. Surprisingly firefox allows it, whereas anything else IE, Chrome, Opera [don't](http://jsfiddle.net/MCLjZ/). Here's the code that tries to style a single `option` in the `select`.

```
<select>
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="" value="" style="display: none;">Select</option>
    <option class="lefty">option 1</option>
    <option>option 2</option>
    <option>option 3</option>
</select>
```

And the css

```
select {
    width: 300px;
}
.lefty {
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: right;
}
```

What you can do however is to padd a option with extra spaces to give the impression of a right indentation, but this is not a very good solution.

Another option is to use something that doesn't rely on the built in browser controls, such as [jQuery SelectBox](http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/) or [SelectBoxIt](http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/) plugin, which you can then style the rendered content because they are not built in browser behaviors, but rather dynamically created DOM elements which can be styled with CSS.

For SelectBoxIt you can use something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.myselect .selectboxit-option-anchor').first().css("text-align", right");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, cross browser select box styling is not currently possible.  This is why there are so many Select Box plugins out there that create DOM elements that mimic a Select Box so users can do custom styling.

If you end up using [SelectBoxIt](http://www.selectboxit.com) and want to do this in CSS you can do this:

```
.selectboxit-option:nth-child(1) {
    text-align: right;
}
```

**Note:** I wrote SelectBoxIt